# Rolex Paris Masters 2018: Federer haven't decided

Tags: tennis, atp

This is something that really confuses me. Federer obviously still haven't decided whether or not he's gonna participate in Paris Masters. Now, how can this be, since all the other players already started? Djokovic, for instance, came to round of 16, and Federer still doesn't know whether he's gonna play?

Does it have anything to do with previous tournament score for a given player? Ie. higher ranked players don't need to start playing before the round of 8, for instance, so that gives them more time to decide whether or not to participate? If this is the

Comment: Please, if you dislike the question, explain why is it poorly written. Help to ask better questions.

Comment: If you look at the [draw of the Paris Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Rolex_Paris_Masters_%E2%80%93_Singles#Section_3), you can see that all 16 seeded players received [bye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bye_(sports)) into the second round. At the moment, only Cilic and Djokovic already played their first match (which is in the 2nd round). I do not know what exactly are the limits until when a player can withdraw, but in this tournament one of the seeds has already done that - Kyle Edmund withdrew from the tournament and was replaced by Matthew Ebden.

Comment: @Martin thanks. Please post this as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Martin in comments:

> If you look at the draw of the [Paris Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Rolex_Paris_Masters_%E2%80%93_Singles#Section_3), you can see that
>   all 16 seeded players received [bye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bye_(sports)) into the second round. At the
>   moment, only Cilic and Djokovic already played their first match
>   (which is in the 2nd round). I do not know what exactly are the limits
>   until when a player can withdraw, but in this tournament one of the
>   seeds has already done that - Kyle Edmund withdrew from the tournament
>   and was replaced by Matthew Ebden